# Contacts of an Account

Tags: apex, contact, account

I have to code a APEX method which receives through parameter an Account object. I don't  (and don't want to) know if this account is already persisted in SFDC database. I just want to iterate on some property to access the contacts which belongs to the Account received as parameter.

Is there someway to do it?
Please let me know if I not clear enough.

Comment: Hi @Saulo, welcome to SFSE. What have you tried so far? Do you have any code of what you have done so far and if so where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi BarCotter. So, I will try post a sample code to explain my doubt.

Comment: `Account acc1 = new Account();
createContactInsideAccount(acc1); //just initialize some contacts (new Contact()) to the Account passed as parameter
List<Contact> contacts = getAccountContacts(acc1); //contacts must have those contacts created into createContactInsideAccount method`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this simple list method that returns all contacts that belongs to the given account:

```
public List<Contact> getContacts(Account acc){
    return new List<Contact>([Select Id From Contact Where AccountId = :acc.id]);
}
```

You still have to add a validation to the method (account not null etc).

Comment: mast0r, tks for your answer. I suppose it will just work for Account that already exists on database. Imagine if, before call getContacts(Account acc), my account was created by a 'new Account()' statement.

Comment: @Saulo If your Account is fresh created and don't have any Contacts then you will get an empty List or null depending on validation in the method.